# Change data source from FTP server to local directory

Tags: r, ftp

I am working with AIMS model developed by APEC Climate center. The model downloads data from ftp server and then calls the `LoadCmip5DataFromAdss` function from datasource.R to load data into the model.

```
#do.call("LoadCmip5DataFromAdss", parameters)
```

On github I found the source code for `LoadCmip5DataFromAdss` which gives the path of an ftp server to download data

```
  LoadCmip5DataFromAdss <- function(dbdir, NtlCode) {

  fname <- paste("cmip5_daily_", NtlCode, ".zip", sep="")

  if(nchar(NtlCode)==4 && substr(NtlCode,1,2)=="US"){
    adss <- "ftp://cis.apcc21.org/CMIP5DB/US/"
  }else{
    adss <- "ftp://cis.apcc21.org/CMIP5DB/"
  }
```

I want to get the data from a local directory instead of downloading because that takes a lot of time. How do I do that?
Where do I find the file containing `LoadCmip5DataFromAdss`  on my PC, because in the setup only datasource.R is given.

Comment: `LoadCmip5DataFromAdss` is just a function not a file!

Comment: are you using a specific package?

Comment: do you mean the R package?

Comment: Sorry. I mean the file in which this function has been placed. I found on github but cannot find on my PC.
I know this is a function. But my question is how do I load data into LoadCmip5DataFromAdss from local directory instead of FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

All that function does is copy the zip file (`cmip5_daily_` + whatever you specified for `NtlCode` + `.zip`) to the directory you specified for `dbdir` after it downloads it then unzips it and removes the ZIP file. Here's the *whole* function from `rSQM`:

```
LoadCmip5DataFromAdss <- function(dbdir, NtlCode) {

  fname <- paste("cmip5_daily_", NtlCode, ".zip", sep="")

  if(nchar(NtlCode)==4 && substr(NtlCode,1,2)=="US"){
    adss <- "ftp://cis.apcc21.org/CMIP5DB/US/"
  }else{
    adss <- "ftp://cis.apcc21.org/CMIP5DB/"
  }

  srcfname <- paste(adss, fname, sep="")
  dstfname <- paste(dbdir, "/", fname, sep = "")
  download.file(srcfname, dstfname, mode = "wb")
  unzip(dstfname, exdir = dbdir)
  unlink(dstfname, force = T)
  cat("CMIP5 scenario data at",NtlCode,"is successfully loaded.\n")
}
```

You can just do something like:

```
unzip(YOUR_LOCAL_NtlCode_ZIP_FILE, exdir = WHERE_YOUR_dbdir_IS)
```

vs use that function.